# Xamarin iOS: What is different between Document Provider and Importing Document

Tags: ios, file, xamarin, share

I am new on iOS. In my application, I need to get files on the phone e.g. pdf, words etc in the phone. I know iOS application  has their own sandbox to work with, they have no idea of other applications.

I have read some of the extension : Document Provider and a older post importing document through this link : https://mobiforge.com/design-development/importing-exporting-documents-ios

Is there any different between the two setup in my requirement? Sorry this is my first time working on iOS.

Comment: This might be worth a read: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_document_picker/

Comment: Yes I have coded the document picker viewer. But i can only see the iCloud files. How do i see the files from other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, iOS does not allows to share files storage between apps from two different developers.

If you own both apps, you can use *App Groups* to share data and files between apps. You can read more about *App Groups*, and how to use the APIs here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/working-with/app-groups/

Comment: I tried to configure the NewBox sample but having setup problem. https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios8/NewBox/ In their screenshot, the iCloud screen have a locations on the right which can choose different provider. How do they have that? At the moment, I can only see iCloud

Comment: In Dropbox application, they have export option to other apps like Add to notes, Twitter, Facebook etc...

Comment: Did you read through the **Setup**? You cannot add your app to the iCloud document picker with developer wild card provisioning profiles.